# itextsharp single word alignment

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, itext

am using itextsharp to convert text to pdf 
I have a justified paragraph ,how can I put the last word of the content in the right corner (alignment right ) in the same last line in the paragraph  .

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried to put the last word in another paragraph
, and put paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
but it comes in another line

Comment: Google for "separator chunks" or "generic tag event". Those are two possible solutions that come to mind. There may be others, but you should try first (and not just ask for an example).

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**
I just cut the  last word and put it in new paragraph and make the leading - 0.0F

 newparagraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
newparagraph.Leading=-0.0F;